# Сформировать данные из файла Excel по ФИО

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Друзья, я новичок в Python, начал только изучать, но возникла задача:
Есть файл `Excel` (как пример 8 строк)
Необходимо написать код что бы на выводе подсчитывались продажи по ФИО всего, например:

```
Иванов:
Премиальный - 2
Базовый - 1

Петров:
Премиальный - 2
Базовый - 2
Новогодний - 1

Итого: 
Базовый - 3
Премиальный - 3
Новогодний - 1
```

используя `openpyxl` я только могу вывести (прочитать строи и столбы) а вот как правильно всё написать пока не хватает знаний (учу) а надо сделать.

Так же попробовал на Pandas но дальше пока не знаю как сделать сортировку:

```
excel_data = pd.read_excel('cardsell.xlsx')
data = pd.DataFrame(excel_data, columns=['Тариф', 'Выдача', 'ФИО'])
print("The content of the file is:\n", data)
```

Comment: Лучше начните изучать `Pandas`, там такие вещи буквально парой строчек делаются, примерно такой же по сути аггрегацией, как в `SQL`.

Comment: Попробуйте что-то типа `print(data.groupby(['ФИО', 'Тариф']).count())` для начала. А если сделать группировку только по `Тариф`, то будет вам итого фактически.

Comment: СПАСИБО!!!!!!!!!!! ОГРОМНОЕ!!!!!